# How to sort a collection based on java.lang.reflect.Field?

Tags: java, reflection, java-stream

I'm stuck in a situation where I only got *Fields* (java.lang.reflect) of a given class.

To help you better imagine, let's say we have code:

```
List<Apple> sortApplesByFieldName(List<Apple> apples, String fieldName) {
    Field field = Apple.class.getDeclaredField(fieldName);

    // some stream logic for sorting using this var
    return apples;
}
```

Note, the class Apple is a regular POJO with private fields and public getters/setters.

Comment: What if the field is not comparable? Like `Scanner`?

Comment: @Michael -> all of the fields will be **comparable** 100 percent.

Comment: Note Michael's answer will create a **new** (sorted) list, rather than sort the given `apples` list in-place. You may want that, but I thought I'd mention it just in case you don't (and if you don't then use `List#sort(Comparator)`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this. It will throw a ClassCastException if the field can't be compared.

Bit ugly, but isn't reflection always.

```
<T extends Comparable<T>> List<Apple> sortApplesByFieldName(List<Apple> apples, String fieldName)
        throws NoSuchFieldException {
    Field field = Apple.class.getDeclaredField(fieldName);

    return apples.stream()
        .sorted(Comparator.comparing(apple -> {
            try {
                return (T) field.get(apple);
            }
            catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work, unfortunately. Says shortly: `Cannot access class members with "private" modifier`.

Comment: @StefanJankovic I believe you need a `field.setAccessible(true)` call.

Comment: @Slaw True, that did the trick.